# Wait for process to finish before proceeding in Java

Tags: java, process

Essentially, I'm making a small program that's going to install some software, and then run some basic commands afterwards to prep that program. However, what is happening is that the program starts its install, and then immediately moves on to the following lines (registration, updates, etc). Of course, that can't happen until it's fully installed, so I'd like to find a way of waiting on the first process before running the second. For example,

```
    Main.say("Installing...");
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dir + "setup.exe /SILENT");
    //Wait here, I need to finish installing first!
    Main.say("Registering...");
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(installDir + "program.exe /register aaaa-bbbb-cccc");
    Main.say("Updating...");
    Process p4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(installDir + "program.exe /update -silent");
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Call [`Process#waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29). Its Javadoc says:

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated.

Bonus: you get the exit value of the subprocess. So you can check whether it exited successfully with code `0`, or whether an error occured (non-zero exit code).

Comment: Some naive designs for installers can perhaps return, invalidly, a 0 exit code for an error. I actually had an issue with this some time ago and it was a pain to debug.

Comment: Yes, that's a valuable warning. I'm referring to the design of the installer being sad.

Comment: Ended up working like a charm with some tweaking. The next problem to hit is the fact that UAC doesn't like my program not being elevated.

Comment: @mthmulders Sorry, I incorrectly assumed the wrong connotation of your comment.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `Process.waitFor()` method

and the doc says

> Causes the current thread to **wait**, if necessary, until the process
>   represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns
>   immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the
>   subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked
>   until the subprocess exits.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running a system command that returns a very long response string, stdin buffer fills up and the process appears to hang. This happened to me with sqlldr. If that appears to be the case then just read from stdin as the process is running.

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand");
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer errorStr = new StringBuffer();
        boolean alreadyWaited = false;
        while (p.isAlive()) {
            try {
                if(alreadyWaited) {

                    // read the output from the command because
                    //if we don't then the buffers fill up and
                    //the command stops and doesn't return
                    String temp;

                    while ((temp = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(temp);
                    }


                    String errTemp;
                    while ((errTemp = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                        errorStr.append(errTemp);
                    }                                                   
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                alreadyWaited = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.debug("Response is " + response);
            logger.debug("Error is: " + errorStr);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error running system command", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Include **waitFor()**. In your case, your code will look something like below.

```
    Main.say("Installing...");
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dir + "setup.exe /SILENT");
    p1.waitFor()
    Main.say("Registering...");
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(installDir + "program.exe /register aaaa-bbbb-cccc");
    Main.say("Updating...");
    Process p4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(installDir + "program.exe /update -silent");
```