# Wait until LibreOffice created file

Tags: java, shell, command-line, libreoffice

I am struggling with LibreOffices headless mode in connection with Java.

My Spring web app generates a ODT, exports it into a PDF file and sends it back to the user via HTTP.

What happens is

1. Generate ODT
2. Execute LibreOffice headless mode (conver-to pdf)
3. Send it to the user

Two and three are happening nearly at the same time resulting in a `FileNotFoundException`. The process runs about 10 seconds on my old PC and in the meantime my controller already tries (and fails) to read the output.

How can I prevent Java from continuing before the command finished. Can this be done through a loop checking every half second if the file is generated or are better ways to do this?

---

This is my code for LibreOffice:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(path + program + convert + outdir + file);
```

And my full command:

```
"C:/progra~2/libreo~1/program/soffice.exe" --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir "C:\Users\MAX-MI~1\AppData\Local\Temp" "C:\Users\MAX-MI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\document-3328884507253560042.odt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the external process does in fact indicate that it has finished by terminating, then you can use `Process.waitFor()`.

If the external process might hang (and you don't want your java application to get stuck), then use the variant of `Process.waitFor(...)` with parameters to specify a timeout.

If the external process *will* not return (e.g. because it is a long running service that doesn't detach ...), or if it may return *before* the required output has been created, then it gets more difficult:

- The simple way is to *poll* for the output file; e.g. by calling `File.exists()`.  This is inefficient, especially if you poll frequently and/or for a long time.  (But you could live with that in a lot of cases.)
- A more complicated way is to use the Java "file watcher" mechanism to get a notification when the file has been created.  On most platforms, this is more efficient than polling.

But the problem with checking when the file has been created is that you don't (in general) know when the external process has finished writing to to file.  If it does write the file in chunks, then you need to implement some kind of heuristic to detect this; e.g. wait N seconds after the last "file update" event.

---

For a specific case, you need to investigate how the external application generates the output, and choose your Java apps "check that it is finished" strategy / heuristics accordingly.  I would expect something like LibreOffice to be "well behaved".

---

Related Question:

- [Wait for process to finish before proceeding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972380/wait-for-process-to-finish-before-proceeding-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

On the Process object returned by runtime.exec(...), you can call the waitFor() method to have your thread wait until the process finishes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()