# Process opened by java on MacOS won't stay open

Tags: java, process

I have been trying to find an answer to this question for quite a while an I am not having any luck.  Below I have an example of a simple program that is supposed to open Skype on my Mac.  Everything compiles and runs fine, but as soon as Skype opens, it closes itself.  How do I make sure it keeps itself open?

```
public class program{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
     new String[]{"open","/Applications/Skype.app"}
     );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Consider using a `ProcessBuilder` instead or `Runtime` directly; 2. Consume the output of the process in order to check if it's outputting any error states; 3. Look at the return of `Process#exitValue` to see if it's returning an error state

Comment: That's because you're spawning a new process as a child of the main java process. As soon as your java program ends, it kills its child. Have you tried [`p.waitFor()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972380/wait-for-process-to-finish-before-proceeding-in-java)?

Comment: You may also be interested in spawning a new process completely indipendent from the java one, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program/931579)