# Command execution time in Java

Tags: java, command-execution

Is there any way to know the execution time of the command? Making `exec` synchronous

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(ffmpeg +" -i "+source+" -vcodec h264 -acodec aac  "+destination);
```

the ffmpeg command is taking time so I want to log something after the execution. Is there any way to log the things after the command has executed?

Comment: So, your basic question comes down to - how to calculate the duration between two points in time. Rather a common problem, but since the date/time APIs have changed since Java 8, it can be a little confusing to find the right answer.   However, if the answer doesn't indulging the `java.time.*` API, then it's not the answer you're looking for.  [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776787/java-simpledateformat-format-issue-with-yyyy/25777559#25777559)

Comment: nope @MadProgrammer I am aware of execution. I want to make this synchronous.. so that execution takes places after the conversion (ffmeg process) has finished.

Comment: So, what's time go to do with it?  Just `waitFor` the process to complete - might want to check the `exitCode` and print a statement

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Possible duplicate [Wait for process to finish before proceeding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972380/wait-for-process-to-finish-before-proceeding-in-java) - again, not an uncommon question, although I'd recommend using `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: " I want to log something after the execution." @MadProgrammer and the logs do their job right after the execution which I want to do be done after theprocess has completed the conversion.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried it but apparently I have missed something. I will give it another try using that.

Answer (score 1):

You could record the time before the process starts, [waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) it to finish, and then record the time again, and subtract the two:

```java
long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process =
    rt.exec(ffmpeg + " -i " + source + " -vcodec h264 -acodec aac  " + destination);
process.waitFor();
long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
long execTime = after - before;
System.out.println("Processing took " + execTime + " milliseconds");
```

Comment: I tested `waitFor()` seems like it halts everything, or maybe I didn't wait much.. Let me give it another try.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: if the process produces any output, then you must consume that output or the process might hang.

Comment: how do we consume it? it generates output but I don't need that output. I just need execution as the output is another file.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Use a `ProcessBuilder` - it will give a lot more capability and configuration options as well as over come some of the issues related to `Process` - as a [crud example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893469/java-execute-a-program-with-options-like-ls-l/11893495#11893495)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right.. `process.waitFor();` is not working on my end. Process builder makes sense